# XML-parser and validator - B2MML

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have some problems validating a XML-file with one of the XSD-schemas from the B2MML standard (More specifically the Materials-schema). We have our code working with other XSD but it just doesnt work with the B2MML one. Our method for handling validating is as follows:

```
public class XMLvalidate {

     public static void Xml2String(String xmlFile){
        // Danner JAVA DOM XML Parser

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =
               DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder builder = null;
       try {
           builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

       // Changes the XML file to XML DOM standard

       try {
           Document document = builder.parse(
                   new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFile)));
           Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
           transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

           // Make the DOM XML file readable
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
          DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
          transformer.transform(source, result);
           String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
           System.out.println(xmlString);
       } catch (SAXException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

 public static void XMLValidator(String xmlFile, String validationFile)throws SAXException, IOException{


        String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
         SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
        ((factory.newSchema(new File(validationFile))).newValidator()).validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile)));


    }

 public static void main(String [] args){
     boolean flag = true;
     try{

            try{XMLValidator("src\\Material.xml", "src\\B2MML-V0600-Material.xsd");}
            catch (SAXException e){ flag = false; } 
            catch (IOException e) { flag = false; }
            System.out.println("XML fil is valid : " + flag);
 }
     catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Link to B2MML: https://github.com/Rubatharisan/radis/blob/master/B2MML-V0600-Material.xsd
Link to our XML-file: https://github.com/Rubatharisan/radis/blob/master/Material.xml

Our XML-file file is auto-generated from the XSD-file via. XMLSpy.

Why doesn't it work with B2MML? Thanks in advance.

The error:

I looked through my program again and i made a mistake in my earlier comment. This Error appeared:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Bj%C3%B8rn/Desktop/Workspace2/XMLValidator/src/B2MML-V0600-Material.xsd; lineNumber: 183; columnNumber: 87; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'Extended:MaterialInformation' to a(n) 'group' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.traverseSeqChoice(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractParticleTraverser.traverseSequence(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at XMLvalidate.XMLValidator(XMLvalidate.java:73)
at XMLvalidate.main(XMLvalidate.java:82)
```

Comment: What is the actual error given by the validate?

Comment: There's no compiler-error. It just prints "false" but i'm sure it should be "true".

Comment: From the information available; i would check your XSLT. The fact it prints out anything, means it seems to be running to completion. Check your XSLT output when using this example XML in Altova

Comment: I'll do that. I will return with the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: I just edited the post with the error.

Comment: You are missing schema's for validation. I'm no expert in java so can't help with class names and such, but i think you need to add the 2 schemas "imported" by your main schema to the schema collection set (or add a resolver that can load those imports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the validator did not succeed in finding the group `Extended:MaterialInformation`.  Without any further investigation, the likeliest explanation for this is that it did not succeed in finding the schema document for that namespace, which is given using the relative URI `B2MML-V0600-AllExtensions.xsd`.

From the wording of the error message, it appears you are using a local copy of `B2MML-V0600-Material.xsd`, so the validator is resolving the relative reference using the base URI of your local copy, and looking (it would appear) for a schema document at `file:/C:/Users/Bj%C3%B8rn/Desktop/Workspace2/XMLValidator/src/B2MML-V0600-AllExtensions.xsd`.  When you made a local copy of the top-level schema document, did you also make local copies of all the schema documents it refers to by means of relative references, in the correct locations?  And similarly for all the schema documents they themselves import, include, or redefine by means of relative references?  And so on recursively?  If so, then perhaps something went wrong in the organization of the local copies; if not, then now you know what you need to do.